# What is a 'symbol'. Specifically within the context of Xcode and iOS development

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

When developing for iOS Xcode often gives warnings or errors referring to **duplicate symbols**. There sometimes other messages related to **symbols**.

What is a symbol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is terminology used within the Compiler and Linker, which is used to provide errors and warnings in Xcode. In its most simple form, a symbol is a way to refer to pieces of code (such as variables, methods etc...), so that the linker can resolve them later on, when it is linking all parts of the application together.

Duplicate symbols are when they have been used more than once, so the linker does not know which one to link to.

This goes well beyond Objective C, and is the basis for C programming/compilation as a whole. As such, there is plenty of material online to read about this stuff. For example:

- http://www.lurklurk.org/linkers/linkers.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)

Answer (score 0):

It's an object in an executable (or object) file. Functions, method calls and global variables are translates into symbols by the compiler - these are essentially parts of the executable that point to the backing memory region of a global variable or the starting address of a function's code.